# How to restart object position in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with refreshing object position, the condition I want to make is pretty easy.
If a game object moves too far by X axis, then restart its position where it was at the beginning

My code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float playerSpeed = 5.0f;
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        startPos = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position;
    }
    
    void restartPlayerPosition() 
    {
        if(transform.position.x > 10 || transform.position.x < 10){ 
            this.transform.position = startPos;
    }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalnput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * playerSpeed * verticalInput);
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.right * playerSpeed * horizontalnput);

        restartPlayerPosition();
    }

}
```

But instead of move back and forth, it rotates, and I don't know why.
The thing I know, is that something wrong happens when I call startPos in the start() method, It is trying to refresh location immediately instead of looking on if statement condition first. Do I miss something?

I've also tried to find position of an object by using this method

```
gameObject.transform.position = sartPos
```

No errors, but won't work as I wanted it to

Comment: if(transform.position.x > 10 || transform.position.x < 10)
The conditions look odd.
In this condition, the condition to return to the original position is only when x = 10.The conditions look odd.
In this condition, the condition to return to the original position is only when x = 10.
and the movement is going to AddForce, so there is a high probability that it will behave strangely even if it returns to the original place. I think we also need information about how it moves in the game view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget the minus for the position to -10 < x < 10.

Change the condition to like this in restartPlayerPosition().

```
if(transform.position.x > 10 || transform.position.x < -10)
```

That's it. It will work.

Comment: Thanks it worked actually, I just didn't paid much attention to the basic algebra :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your RestartPlayerPosition method with this:

```
void restartPlayerPosition() 
{
    if(transform.position.x > (startPos.x +10) || transform.position.x < (startPos.x - 10)
    { 
        this.transform.position = startPos;
    }
}
```